# Identify the set from this partially assembled purple and white car with a blue flower sticker on the hood?

Tags: set-identification

I have loads of complete Lego sets, distributed into bags and without instructions.

[image: incomplete model of purple and magenta car with a blue flower sticker on the hood]

Comment: Hi Nick! I took the liberty and edited your question in the hopes that it will better reflect your intent. Should I have made an error and misinterpreted your thoughts, feel free to revert or edit your question.

Comment: No problem - a novice here so all help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [41013-1: Emma's Sports Car](https://brickset.com/sets/41013-1/Emma-s-Sports-Car): [image]

Comment: Hi Nick! Glad to hear it was useful :) Please click the Checkmark icon to signal to others that the question has been answered.

Comment: Is that right? I have plenty more

Comment: Perfect, bring on the other questions ;)